# Raspberry Pi (armhf) cross compiler fails to compile C code that includes a library (eg. usb.h)

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, libusb

I need to control the USB ports of a Raspberry Pi 1 B+ in order to disconnect/reconnect USB devices without physically accessing the machine/cable.

I have found [`hub-ctrl.c`](https://github.com/codazoda/hub-ctrl.c) which seems to be just fine (according to [this "Raspberry Pi B+ turn usb power off" topic on raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1030423#p1030423)) but it must be compiled.

And I want to do it from my Linux amd64 machine (so I could easily compile other stuff in the future), so I need a cross compiler (because the Raspberry Pi uses an ARM CPU).

I am using [`abhiTronix/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers`](https://github.com/abhiTronix/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers) which works (a simple Hello World C code compiles and run on the Raspberry Pi just fine).

But, for `hub-ctrl.c` the compilation fails because the C code needs an external include: `#include <usb.h>`.

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codazoda/hub-ctrl.c/master/hub-ctrl.c
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc hub-ctrl.c -o hub-ctrl -lusb
hub-ctrl.c:12:10: fatal error: usb.h: No such file or directory
   12 | #include <usb.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I did installed the dev `libusb` packages for both architecture (on my compilation computer):

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libusb
ii  libusb-0.1-4:amd64     2:0.1.12-32 amd64 userspace USB programming library
ii  libusb-1.0-0:amd64     2:1.0.22-2  amd64 userspace USB programming library
ii  libusb-1.0-0:armhf     2:1.0.22-2  armhf userspace USB programming library
ii  libusb-1.0-0-dev:amd64 2:1.0.22-2  amd64 userspace USB programming library development files
ii  libusb-1.0-0-dev:armhf 2:1.0.22-2  armhf userspace USB programming library development files
ii  libusb-1.0-doc         2:1.0.22-2  all   documentation for userspace USB programming
```

I don't understand how I can tell the compiler it should use it (and from which place).

Part of the `abhiTronix/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers` installation sets the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable but it does not points to a place where the library files are.

Update 1 :

As requested in the comments here is the list of files the `libusb-1.0-0-dev` package installed :

```
$ dpkg -L libusb-1.0-0-dev:armhf
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/libusb-1.0
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/README
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/copyright
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
```

Also, the "usb" files I have :

```
$ find / -iname "*usb*" | grep arm
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
# Omitting linux-headers, dpkg and apt paths
/opt/cross-pi-gcc-9.3.0-0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/sound/usb_stream.h
/opt/cross-pi-gcc-9.3.0-0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/linux/usb
/opt/cross-pi-gcc-9.3.0-0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/linux/usbdevice_fs.h
/opt/cross-pi-gcc-9.3.0-0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/linux/usbip.h
```

Update 2 :

According to [this other StackOverFlow question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190940/compiling-a-libusb-0-1-program-fails-with-undefined-reference-errors) since the source code uses `#include <usb.h>` I should be using the `libusb-dev` Debian package instead of `libusb-1.0-0-dev`.

I did it, but without changes to the outcome of the compilation:

```
$ apt-get install libusb-dev:armhf
$ dpkg -L libusb-dev:armhf
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/libusb-config
/usr/include
/usr/include/usb.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.a
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libusb.pc
# Omitting "/usr/share/doc" and "/usr/share/man"
```

Comment: Is that header available on your file system? You might need to tell the compiler to use an extra include folder.

Comment: have you tried installing the amd64 version of libusb-dev?

Comment: @Gerhardh It should be. I'm pretty sure that "tell the compiler to use..." is the part I'm not doing right.
@ChoKaPeek, I had `libusb-1.0-0-dev:amd64` (on a previous less cleaner setup) and it also failed, re-installed it: same issue. (I'll update the original post)

Comment: "It should be" does not answer the question. Is it there? Did you search for it? You might check using `dpkg -L libusb-1.0-0-dev:armhf`. From your command line you do not provide any include folders at all.

Comment: I updated my answer with `dpkg -L` and `find -iname "*usb.so*"` commands. What is missing in my command line to provide include folder/file?

Comment: The raspberry ubuntu has a very nice native compiler. Why cross-compile?

Comment: Maybe I don't have a Raspberry Pi available for compilation right now? Maybe I want my compile to go faster than on the slow ARM CPU of a RPi?

Comment: According to this other quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442638/whats-the-difference-between-libusb-h-and-usb-h-in-ubuntu-which-one-is-better it looks like I should be using the `libusb-dev` package instead of `libusb-1.0-0-dev`. I installed it but the problem remains the same (I don't know how to tell the compiler where to look for "usb.h" file)

Comment: @CDuv : your question is a week old. But you still want to compile fast?

Comment: Please stop asking (trolling?) why not using X or Y instead of Z. Cross-compiling C code that includes `usb.h` is a legitimate question.