# What is the advantage and disadvantage of using libusb.h versus usb_srs_vendor_v1_2.h versus usb.h in Linux?

Tags: usb, libusb

I want to do USB programming to control another device, to read and to write from/to a device, and so on. I watched many videos/tutorials in Youtube, and I found three ways/headers to do that purpose. They are (the links are link to videos that use the header respectively):

1. Using [libusb.h](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cT3fUzuzkAs),
2. using [usb_srs_vendor_v1_2.h](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBxK9LZDDog), and
3. Using [usb.h](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IDL070RtoQ).

I have difficulty to understand which one should I follow if I want to do that USB programming, but so far I found that the easiest way is using libusb.h. But I am not sure, maybe just because I am new to this USB programming so still to early for me to decide. I found, the first two are user mode programming while the third one is kernel mode. So my question, what is their different, what is the advantage and the disadvantage of using them? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442638/whats-the-difference-between-libusb-h-and-usb-h-in-ubuntu-which-one-is-better) One has asked the different between the 1st and the 3rd, but no the 2nd one. According to one answer there that is not accepted, it is better to use libusb. But as it is just compare two, still remain one more unanswered.

Ask insight, explanation about their different.

Answer (score 0):

Just use libusb-1.0 and its header, libusb.h.  The usb_srs thing appears to be a library that runs on AVRs, so it probably is irrelevant for you since you are writing a program that runs Linux, not an AVR.  The usb.h header is the interface for the older library libusb-0.1, and there is no reason to use that library in new projects.  There might also be a header file named usb.h in the Linux kernel, but I don't think that will be relevant for you.

For more information about libusb-1.0, see https://libusb.info/ .